# select a specific radiobutton in a form

Tags: jquery

I have a html form in my page. I want a jQuery script that reads only the radio buttons in the form.

HTML code:

```
<form method="post" action="#"  id="srf" name="form" class="srf">
   <p><input type="radio" class="radioButton" value="web Applciaiton" id="webapp"/></p>
   <p><input type="radio" class="radioButton" value="uplaods" id="uploads"/></p>
   <p><input type="radio" class="radioButton" value="sync" id="sync" /></p>
</form>
```

JS so far:

```
$('input[type="radio"]').click(function() {
  }
```

This code is triggered when any radio button is clicked. I want it to trigger when any radio button with the class "radioButton" in the form with class "srf" is clicked.

So far, I came up with this:

```
$("#srf input[type="radio"]").click(function() {
}
```

But it doesn't check for radio button's class.  Is there a way I can do that?

Thanks.

Comment: `$("#srf input[type='radio'].radioButton")`.  You can just add multiple attribute checks to a selector.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use the class that point

```
$("#srf .radioButton").click(function() {

}
```

Or if you wish to have a more specific selector for only inputs of type button with that class

```
$("#srf input[type='radio'].radioButton").click(function() {

}
```

(using the `.radioButton` suffix here will limit matches to only elements with that class)